# Jquery localscroll and hashtags

Tags: jquery

I'm using localscroll jquery plugin, and I wanted a safe option when someone enter's url with hashtag at the end of url, so I wrote these lines of code:

```
        if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a1").addClass("sel");
      $('#about,#collections,#contact,#brides,#gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "#about") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a2").addClass("sel");
      $('#home,#collections,#contact,#brides,#gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "#collections") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a3").addClass("sel");
      $('#about, #home, #contact, #brides, #gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "#brides") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a4").addClass("sel");
      $('#about, #collections, #contact, #home, #gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "#gallery") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a5").addClass("sel");
      $('#about, #collections, #home, #contact, #brides').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "#contact") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a6").addClass("sel");
      $('#about, #collections, #home, #brides, #gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    } else if (window.location.hash == "") {
      $('#menu-main a').removeClass('sel');
      $("#a1").addClass("sel");
      $('#about,#collections,#contact,#brides,#gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    }
```

But, there definately must be better solution for this, some foreach function maybe, and since I'm not really a jquery guru, I'd like to ask for your advice ...

Thanks, Mart

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, if anyone is interested in my solution:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var cats = {}; 

cats['#home'] = 'a1'; 
cats['#about'] = 'a2'; 
cats['#collections'] = 'a3'; 
cats['#brides'] = 'a4'; 
cats['#gallery'] = 'a5'; 
cats['#contact'] = 'a6'; 
cats[''] = 'a1'; 

$("#menu-main a").removeClass('sel');
$("#" + cats[hash]).addClass("sel");

if (!hash){
  $('#about,#collections,#contact,#brides,#gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);  
} else {
  $.each(cats, function(key, value) {
    if (key != hash){
        $(key).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeSelect(){
var hash = window.location.hash;
$("#menu-main a").removeClass('sel');
$("#"+hash).addClass("sel");
$('#about,#collections,#contact,#brides,#gallery').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
}
```

you can use something like this, if you can change object names to hash values, or make an hash-map for them